# Animated point following a sinusoidal path on sphere

Tags: plotting, animation

Could someone help me with animating a point following a $\sin$-like path on the sphere?
It should be something like this:

This green point should walking on a sine (this red line) around sphere.

[image]

Comment: Would you not derive a formula of a line along which your point should travel?

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 6):

Here you go,

```
sphereplot = With[
   {z = 1/2 Cos[8 ϕ], r = 1},
   Show[
    Graphics3D@Sphere[],
    ParametricPlot3D[{Cos[ϕ] Sqrt[r^2 - z^2], 
      Sin[ϕ] Sqrt[r^2 - z^2], z}, {ϕ, 0, 2 π}],
    Boxed -> False
    ]
   ];
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now you just need a function that will place the animation point at a given angle around the curve,

```
ball[ϕ_] := With[
  {z = 1/2 Cos[8 ϕ], r = 1},
  Show[sphereplot, 
   Graphics3D[{Red, 
     Sphere[{Cos[ϕ] Sqrt[r^2 - z^2], Sin[ϕ] Sqrt[r^2 - z^2],
        z}, .1]}],
   ViewPoint -> {1.8, -2.8, 0.37},
   ViewVertical -> {0.255, -0.4, 0.9},
   PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
   ]]
```

Now you generate a list of images,

```
imglist = ball /@ Range[0, 2 π, .05];
```

and animate with [`ListAnimate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListAnimate.html)

```
ListAnimate@imglist
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[f]
f[p_, a_] := {Cos[a Sin[p #1]] Cos[#1], Cos[a Sin[p #1]] Sin[#1], 
  -Sin[a Sin[p #1]]} &;

sphere = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.7], Sphere[]}];

Dynamic[Show[sphere, ParametricPlot3D[f[10, .25][u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Mesh -> {{{Clock[{0, 2 Pi}], {Red, PointSize[.05]}}}}, 
    MeshFunctions -> {#4 &}], Boxed -> False] /. Point[x_] :> Sphere[x, .05]]
```

[image]

```
Manipulate[Animate[Show[sphere, ParametricPlot3D[f[p, a][u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     Mesh -> {{{t, Directive[Red, PointSize[Large]]}}}, 
     MeshFunctions -> {#4&}] /. {Line[x_] :> Tube[x, .025], Point[x_] :> Sphere[x, .05]}], 
  {t, 0, 2 Pi}], {{a, .5}, 0, 1, .1}, {{p, 4}, 2, 10, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
With[{path = CoordinateTransform[
    "Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {1, (Sin[5 fi] .5 + Pi/2), fi}
 ]}
 ,
 Show[
  ParametricPlot3D[path, {fi, -Pi, Pi}],
  Graphics3D[{Sphere[], AbsolutePointSize @ 12, 
     Dynamic[Point[1.01 path /. fi -> Clock[2 Pi, 3]], UpdateInterval -> .05]}],
  PlotRange -> 1.5]
 ]
```

[image]